# Drawing a half arrow using loops in Java

Tags: java, loops

I'm trying to draw a half arrow in Java and continuously get the same error upon running the code. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong and any assistance would be great.

Instructions: This program outputs a downwards facing arrow composed of a rectangle and a right triangle. The arrow dimensions are defined by user specified arrow base height, arrow base width, and arrow head width.

(1) Modify the given program to use a loop to output an arrow base of height arrowBaseHeight. (1 pt)

(2) Modify the given program to use a loop to output an arrow base of width arrowBaseWidth. Use a nested loop in which the inner loop draws the *’s, and the outer loop iterates a number of times equal to the height of the arrow base. (1 pt)

(3) Modify the given program to use a loop to output an arrow head of width arrowHeadWidth. Use a nested loop in which the inner loop draws the *’s, and the outer loop iterates a number of times equal to the height of the arrow head. (2 pts)

(4) Modify the given program to only accept an arrow head width that is larger than the arrow base width. Use a loop to continue prompting the user for an arrow head width until the value is larger than the arrow base width. (1 pt)

Example output for arrowBaseHeight = 5, arrowBaseWidth = 2, and arrowHeadWidth = 4:

Enter arrow base height: 5
Enter arrow base width: 2
Enter arrow head width: 4
**
**
**
**
**

---

---

**
*
My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DrawHalfArrow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        int arrowBaseHeight;
        int arrowBaseWidth;
        int arrowHeadWidth;

        System.out.print("Enter arrow base height: ");
        arrowBaseHeight = scnr.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter arrow base width: ");
        arrowBaseWidth = scnr.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter arrow head width: ");
        arrowHeadWidth = scnr.nextInt();
        while (arrowHeadWidth <= arrowBaseWidth) {
            System.out.print("Enter arrow head width: ");
            arrowHeadWidth = scnr.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 0; i < arrowBaseHeight; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arrowBaseWidth; j++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        for (int i = arrowHeadWidth; i > 0; i--) {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: <quote>I'm trying to draw a half arrow in Java and continuously get the same error upon running the code. </quote>    What error?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please help us help you by explaining *exactly* what happens when you try running the code (for example, if an error occurs, copy and paste the *complete* error message, formatted as code) and how that is different from what you expect to happen. It would also help to give some indication of where your changes are in this code, compared to "the given program" which we can't see here.

Answer (score 1):

You just had some print line problems and other white space issues between the ":"

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class DrawHalfArrow {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
     int arrowBaseHeight;
      int arrowBaseWidth;
      int arrowHeadWidth;


      System.out.println("Enter arrow base height:");
    
      arrowBaseHeight = scnr.nextInt();

      System.out.println("Enter arrow base width:");
 
      arrowBaseWidth = scnr.nextInt();

      System.out.println("Enter arrow head width:");
   
      arrowHeadWidth = scnr.nextInt();
  
      while (arrowHeadWidth <= arrowBaseWidth) {
          System.out.println("Enter arrow head width:");
          arrowHeadWidth = scnr.nextInt();
      }

      System.out.println();
      for (int i = 0; i < arrowBaseHeight; i++) {
          for (int j = 0; j < arrowBaseWidth; j++) {
              System.out.print("*");
          }
          System.out.println();
      }

      for (int i = arrowHeadWidth; i > 0; i--) {
          for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
              System.out.print("*");
          } 
          System.out.println();
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be running fine (here's it running on a code runnier: https://code.sololearn.com/c6Ww6ZpVv6vI/#java), what error are you getting?